# Batch file logic failing

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, anaconda, tabpy

I'm trying to get a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) to execute the following code:

```
cmd /K C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
cd C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tabpy_server\
run startup.bat
```

The first line execute properly and opens an [anaconda](/questions/tagged/anaconda) [python](/questions/tagged/python) [command-prompt](/questions/tagged/command-prompt) window. The next lines fail to execute.

What am I missing?

The idea is to create a batch file which can be added to [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) [task-scheduler](/questions/tagged/task-scheduler) to start the [tabpy](/questions/tagged/tabpy) server service.

Comment: The is no `run` command in windows.

Comment: Fair enough. The line prior still does not execute the change of directory.

Comment: It is waiting for you to exit the new command prompt you opened. Type `start /?`, `cmd /?`.

Comment: Not only that, but that window sets up your environment, but when it closes/finishes, that environment isn't passed to your running script. If you need that environment, I would suggest you use `Call` instead of `cmd /K`. Once `activate.bat` has completed, control will be returned to your [tag:batch-file].

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Changing to the "call" command resolved my issue. I feel so dumb.

Comment: Yes, use `call` instead of `run` and `cmd /K`; and use `cd /D` rather than `cd`...

Answer (score 0):

There is no `run` command in batch. What you want is the `start` command. Also you want to use `call` instead of `cmd /k` because it is used for starting another instance of cmd while you just want to call the batch file. Here is an example:

```
call C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
cd C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tabpy_server\
start startup.bat
```